# YouTube's "Use a full name feature" delete all my favorites, how can I recover them?

Tags: youtube

I have been a long time YouTube user, and it continually prompts me to use my real name.  I keep on saying no.

Now, it appears that my full name is being used, and all my favorites are gone.  My watch history is still present.

How can I contact Google to fix this?

I have the number for AdWords, but that department isn't going to assist with YouTube.

Comment: also you could call google's nexus line  https://support.google.com/nexus/   Call 0800.328.6081 (customers in the United Kingdom) or 1800.108.8485 (customers in India) for support    I wouldn't use youtube favorites, they are limited too. You could make a text file with links to all your favorites. It's far more reliable. You can't really trust youtube or google for these things.  Not really a good idea to use youtube on your proper email account. similarly not a good idea to use facebook on your email account. these things can get linked.

Comment: Try this (dont know if it still work coz it's kinda old) http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ddvs-RC-S0I and in case the only problem you face is not finding the firefox extension as some users have commented, you could use ytd downloader for windows or youtube-dl for linux i guess... again i'm not answering coz billion things have change but worth a shot

Comment: Calling 650 253 0000 - youtube.com/tt/contact_us option 5,3 and they told me to go to google.com/support